# Neo4j GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: caching, memory, neo4j

I was running a test and I got a "GC overhead limit exceeded" error.
I understood that it is because I loaded too many primitives in the cache. Am I wrong?

My question then, is how can we prevent ourselves from this?
For example, can we evaluate the size of needed memory based on the number of primitives? Is there like a tip to approximatively know about it?

My boss want to know how many primitives can we manage at the same time.
I assume it is related to JVM settings but can't manage to find which settings.

Sorry if it is dumb questions, I'm not used to JVM settings and peformance and I have a pretty huge lack of knowledge about it atm. Trying and willing to understand though!

Jimmy.

Comment: Have you tried running your java process with more memory? How much RAM does your machine have? You might want to try adding "-Xms1g" as a VM argument or allocate even more memory.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was helping to add/uncomment the following lines in **neo4j-wrapper.conf**:

```
wrapper.java.initmemory=4096
wrapper.java.maxmemory=4096
```

The problem is the RAM size.

You can find this file in "C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\neo4j-community-2.1.3\conf" on a Windows system e.g.

PS: another good article on what else could help you (http://jexp.de/blog/2014/06/load-csv-into-neo4j-quickly-and-successfully/).

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the details of Java garbage collections is by far not a trivial thing. Since you're question is rather unspecific, I can just provide a rather unspecific answer as well. There's a section in the Neo4j reference manual on JVM settings, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-jvm.html.

Another idea depending on your graph and heap size is to change the implementation type for the object cache. There is a `soft` (default in community edition), `weak` and `strong` cache implementation. Additionally the enterprise edition comes with `hpc` (high performance cache) implementation which significantly reduces the number of full garbage collections by dynamically adjusting the cache size. For more read http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-caches.html#_object_cache.